# Set the Default Styles from a Project using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, style

I would like to make sure that when I create or import a layer, it has a different default style than what QGIS offers.

I saw that there was a "Default Styles" option in the project properties (see screenshot below) but in order not to have to modify this option for each project that I open, I would like to integrate a function in my startup.py modifying it.
[image: Project Properties - Default Styles dialog]

As this is an option present in the project properties, I looked at the documentation of the `QgsProject` class. But I couldn't find any function that could change the default style of the layers in the project.

I then thought of creating a function that would modify the style of the layers added to the project (via the `layersAdded` signal).

But I would have liked to know if it was possible to modify the Default Styles option of QGIS projects from using PyQGIS?